# Half of the icons are not showing after upgrading to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, icons

I just run a `do-release-upgrade` to update from 18.04 to 20.04 and now most of my icons are not showing

[image: screenshot]

I have no idea why it is. Maybe it will help to do a clean reinstall of 20.04, but how?

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*` or `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache`? Maybe you need to regenerate the icons cache

Comment: Nothing changed... I ended up reinstalling 20.04 from scratch :/